# How liquify / warp works photoshop

Tags: image-processing

How liquify / warp works photoshop

This video shows what I mean:

https://youtu.be/zkfZzbRAuJ0

I want to create a liquar / warp effect of photoashop in my application
  graphics app, but I have no idea where to start.

I want the mirror effect that is created by doubling the pixels many times, the pixels overlap and disappear and reappear are discovered.

How does photoshop to keep the pixels overlapping and then rebuild them when they are overlapping.

Comment: The main way is to map the image as a texture to a flat 3D mesh, then translate modes of the mesh. This is how _Kai’s Power Goo_ worked and I believe Photoshop’s warp tool uses the same fundamental method of operation.

Comment: Do you have the source code or link to download the tool?